# Let $f$ be a real valued differentiable function on the real line such that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ exists, and is finite . Prove $f'(0)=0.$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Let $f$ be a real  valued differentiable function on the real line $\Bbb R$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ exists, and is finite . Prove that $f'(0)=0$

My solution goes  like this:

> Given, $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}.$$ Now, we have $f$ differentiable over the real  line, this implies that $f$ is differentiable everywhere. Now, as $f$ is differentiable everywhere, this means that that $f$ is continuous everywhere as well. If $f(0)=r$ such that $r\neq 0$ then if $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=\frac{f(0)}{0}=L$ then $L=\infty$ but this is not possible as it is mentioned in the question that, $L$ is finite. So, we can conclude $f(0)=0.$ We know that $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{xf(x)}{x^2}=0\times L=0.$$ This completes the proof.

However, I feel unsure that whether  my "process" or rather my way of conccluding $f(0)=0$ is justified or not? I get somewhat of an uncanny feeling from this part of my proof. Iff that is valid, then is my proof a completely justified approach?

Comment: I guess you wanted to write
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$$
exists instead of
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(0)}{x^2}.$$

Comment: $f(x)/x^2$ is not continuous at $x=0$, so writing $f(0)/0$ doesn't make sense. Second, $r/0$ is not infinity. You're on the right track though.

Comment: @DavidP I dont get one thing, as $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere and $x^2$  is as well. But I don't get your reasoning...

Comment: @Falcon Made a typo there. Sorry ... Is the solution ok?

Comment: @FdstZfsy Just because $f(x),g(x)$ are continuous, it is not necessarily true that $f(x)/g(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: @DavidP Yeah, that's true, but I really dont see any so-called "loophole" in my approach!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler, more rigorous way to conclude $f(0) = 0$: suppose $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)/x^2 = L$, then because $f$ is continuous and $L$ is finite,
$$
f(0) = \lim_{x\to0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2f(x)}{x^2} = \left(\lim_{x\to0} x^2\right)\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\right) = 0\cdot L = 0.
$$
The rest of your solution looks correct from there. Fun fact, if $f''(0)$ exists, then the limit in question must be $L = \frac12f''(0)$ due to L'Hospital's rule and the fact that $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: That's indeed a nice way of  doing or rather showing $f(0)=0.$ But I am looking for a validation if my approach for concluding $f(0)=0$ is  valid or not?

Comment: Well, your argument is not particularly rigorous, division by zero notwithstanding--it only works because of the line shown in my answer. More generally, if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)/g(x)$ exists and is finite, and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = 0$, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ also, and this is why.

Comment: @BrianMoehring You are right, I've edited my answer to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the correct solution, but give a counterexample if it is wrong.

Let $f$ be a real valued differentiable function on the real line $\mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ exists, and is finite. Prove that f′(0)=0.

For the given limit to exsist (I think) that the function $f(x)$ has to be a polynomial of degree higher than $n=2$ so the terms can cancel and the limit will not blow up because of the denominator.

So for any polynomial $p(x) = a x^n + b x^{n-1} + \cdots$ , $n>2$ the limit will exsist.

Now to show that $f(0)' = 0$, we can see that the last term in the polynomial (the one without x will be $0$ after derivation and all the other terms with $x$ in them will be $0$ when we input $0$ as we have to. So that is it.

$f(0)' = 0$ and the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ exists.

Comment: That is wrong. If, say, $f(x)=1-\cos(x)$, then $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=\frac12$, but $f$ is *not* a polynomial function.

Comment: Also, $(x^3+x)/x^2$ is a counter-example for $f(x)$ being a polynomial.

Comment: Good examples, thanks!